# Static files not loading on ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having a an issue when I try to redirect to action to another controller. I have two controllers A & B and I am trying to redirect to Controller B from Controller A. In controller B, I have two action methods, 1. Index and 2 IndexTest, if I redirect to "Index" from Controller A then all static files (css javascripts) are loading correctly but if I try to redirect to "IndexTest" then static files are not loaded and in Chrome, if I inspect then I can see 404 error message "Failed to load resources".

[error in loading static files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRfg5.png)

Below is the code from controller A

```
    public IActionResult Test(string userprofiles)
    {
        TempData["mydata"] = userprofiles;
        return RedirectToAction( "IndexLoad", "Home");
        //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

And in Controller B

```
    public IActionResult IndexLoad()
    {
        string dvms = TempData["mydata"] as string;
        DFUNCTIONS dx = new DFUNCTIONS();
        UserViewModel uv = dx.DeSerializeUserData(dvms);
        DICEViewModel dvm = new DICEViewModel();
        string ux = dx.SerializeUserData(uv.userprofile, uv.userdatainfo);
        dvm.userinfo = ux;
        return View("HomeView", dvm);

    }


    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string dvms = TempData["mydata"] as string;
        DFUNCTIONS dx = new DFUNCTIONS();
        UserViewModel uv = dx.DeSerializeUserData(dvms);
        DICEViewModel dvm = new DICEViewModel();
        string ux = dx.SerializeUserData(uv.userprofile, uv.userdatainfo);
        dvm.userinfo = ux;
        return View("HomeView", dvm);

    }
```

Page loads correctly if redirected to Index but not when "IndexLoad" in controller B.
Could someone help me understand what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: It's impossible to say anything for sure with what you've provided. My best guess is that you're using relative paths for the static files, i.e. `js/foo.js`. Instead, you should be using app-relative paths like `~/js/foo.js`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this. I noticed that in my Layout file there were 3 links which were not set to relative, once I fixed them, it is working fine, but I am wondering why it was rendering correctly if I redirect to Index method?